# Can we check current multiple sessions with OR in php?

Tags: php, session

Two sessions were started on two different pages. Both pages are redirected to one common page.

can I check if atleast one session isset or not with OR ?

e.g.

```
$_SESSION['page1'];
```

is on one page

AND

```
$_SESSION['page2'];
```

is on page 2.

Now I want to check session on Page 3.

Can I use code like below ?

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['page1'])) || (isset($_SESSION['page2']))) {
```

I want to check with "OR" And not to check if both sessions exist.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is correct

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['page1'])) || (isset($_SESSION['page2']))) {
    //do what you want to do with that
}
```